# System Administrator - Insufficient Privileges over everything

Tags: permissions, permission-sets

So I messed up the permissions, basically I created a permission set and check everything and clicked save. Right after I logged in I was blasted with 'Insufficient Privileges'. If I click setup it kick me out. I can't navigate through pages and I can't click profile or anything. I just says 'Insufficient Privileges'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are you have  API only user checked.

Please see this article for more info https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000198764&language=en_US

The only Profile with the "Manage Users" permission has accidentally set the "API Only User" permission and unable to login to salesforce using the User Interface.

This prevents the System Administrator to log into salesforce using the User Interface.

This problem can occur in one of two ways:
1. The "API Only User" perm has been set at the profile level, for the only Sys Admin profile in an org

2. A Permission Set has been assigned at the User level, to the only Sys Admin user in an org

**Resolution**
The steps below can be used to fix this issue when "API Only User" has been set at the profile level:

Step 1. Login using the Data Loader.
Step 2. Export the Profile object.
Step 3. Update the "PERMISSIONSAPIUSERONLY column with False for your Profile.
Step 4. Perform the update.

You will now be able to login through the User Interface

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003819&language=en_US

Comment: I tried to follow the instructions but it tells me: 'Go to the User Detail page.' I can't find it. I can't navigate onto any page/setting.

Comment: Try this https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003819&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the field using Workbench.developerforce.com . If the issue is the Api only field then you will want to select "Profile" as the object for updating. Create a csv file with the user id you need to update and the PermissionsApiUserOnly field with a value of false.

As an alternative couldn't someone push over the old settings from a sandbox environment?

Comment: Yup, same answer as posted above. Thank you, this saved me! I would accept both as good answers but I only can 1 and he answerd first, sorry.